# Google App Engine with Python 2.7 - CouldNotFindModuleError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am new to Google App Engine, so i was trying to learn from this tutorial

http://www.vogella.de/articles/GoogleAppEngine/article.html#installation

and i followed all the steps, and when i run the application this is what appears in the browser when i got to localhost:8080

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3245, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3186, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 531, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2410, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2320, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2211, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    handler_path, cgi_path, import_hook)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2112, in LoadTargetModule
    module_code = import_hook.get_code(module_fullname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1295, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1972, in get_code
    full_path, search_path, submodule = self.GetModuleInfo(fullname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1295, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1925, in GetModuleInfo
    source_file, pathname, description = self.FindModuleRestricted(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1295, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1694, in FindModuleRestricted
    raise CouldNotFindModuleError()
CouldNotFindModuleError
```

so i really dont know what is the problem , can any one help me please

i am using python 2.7

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere? (github, bitbucket ...)

Comment: [Python 2.7 is now supported in Google AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/newin27.html#Supported_Datastore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Python 2.7 with Google App Engine. Use Python 2.5. This is what runs on the production servers, and Google makes no effort to ensure that SDK will work at all on Python 2.7. They have fixed at least one bug that occurred when running with Python 2.6, but considering the syntax changes between 2.6 and 2.5, using 2.6 as a testing environment is a bad idea; you're fairly likely to have code that runs perfectly on the dev server and fails horribly in production.

EDIT: 
An experimental Python 2.7 runtime is now available for App Engine; the SDK may now work fine with Python 2.7.

Comment: okey thanks!, i am downloading now python 2.5, i will check it and back to you, thanks

Comment: i have installed python2.5, i changed "Python Path" in the pertinence of Google Apps Engine, to Python 2.5, and i still get the same error !!

Comment: If you're getting the same error, I'd suspect that python 2.7 is still getting run by Windows, unless your application is trying to import a module that you don't have installed.

Answer (score 1):

I also found the same issue, i then changed to [this tutorial](http://blog.fruiapps.com/2012/04/simple-google-app-engine-tutorial-using-webapp2-jinja2-in-python-2-7), maybe if the issue has not been resolved for you, you might want to read the one mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need [AppEngine Python SDK 1.6.0](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python)+